# pipをインストールし、Flaskパッケージをインストールしたがそのモジュールが使えない。

Tags: python

タイトルの通りです。私は「独学プログラマー」という本で学んでいる初心者です。その本に、bashからpipをインストールし、flaskを使おうというものがありました。手順通りに進めたところ、successfully installed と出てきました。
そしてPythonで

```
from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello, World!"


app.run(port='8000')
```

と打つと対話シェルに

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/TAKA/Documents/flask.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
  File "/Users/TAKA/Documents/flask.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ImportError: cannot import name 'Flask' from partially initialized module 'flask' (most likely due to a circular import) (/Users/TAKA/Documents/flask.py)
```

と表示されます。何が問題なのでしょうか？

気がかりな点としては、bashには現在のpython は3.7.6と出てくるのに対して、対話シェルではver3.8.5 表示されていることです。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 原因はエラーメッセージに `due to a circular import` とある通り、モジュール名(`flask`) とスクリプトのファイル名(`flask.py`) が同じだから、です。

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。ファイル名をnot.pyにしてやり直して見ましたが、以下のように同じ文を返されました。

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/TAKA/Documents/not.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
  File "/Users/TAKA/Documents/flask.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ImportError: cannot import name 'Flask' from partially initialized module 'flask' (most likely due to a circular import) (/Users/TAKA/Documents/flask.py)

Comment: エラーメッセージの最後に `(most likely due to a circular import) (/Users/TAKA/Documents/flask.py)`  とありますので、元の `flask.py` が同じディレクトリに残ったままになっている様です。`flask.py` を削除するか別のディレクトリに移動して下さい。

Comment: まだ循環していたみたいなのでpc上の全てのflask.pyを消してみました。すると新しいエラーが出ました。以下の通りです。

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/TAKA/Downloads/SpaceTAKA/not.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コメントの方にfalsk.pyを消去とあり、それを実行したと仮定した話をします。

今回のエラーは使用している環境にそのパッケージがないことを示しています。
質問文の方にpipを使用してる旨が記載されているので、

```
pip install flask
```

を実行することでエラーが解決する可能性があります。